# Spring security not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security with the below configuration. Every time i try to access the root url i.e. '/', it takes me to '/verify'. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/verify" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('SUPER','ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login login-page="/verify" default-target-url="/home"
            username-parameter="user_email" password-parameter="user_password"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/verify"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" logout-url="/logoutuser" />
        <headers>
            <cache-control />
            <hsts />
        </headers>
    </http>
```

My controller

```
@Controller
public class VerifyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/verify")
    public String userVerification() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u pls add /verify request mapping and it's JSP page?

Comment: I have added the request mapping. The JSP is just a simple login page.

Comment: You should try to use a log level of debug for `org.springframework.security.*` and show the log (for the part relevant to an access to `/`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you for the URL pattern "/**" instruct SS to run isAuthenticated()

Could that trigger the redirect to /verify?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure of it, but a common pitfall is to forget to allow access to resource files, images, css, or js that are used by public HTML or JSP pages (eventually through controllers).

If it is your problem, my advice is to put them either under a `resources` folder, or rather under `images`, `css`, and `js` folders and add corresponding lines in Spring Security config :

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        ...
</http>
```

Comment: I have all my resources in the 'resources' folder but for this page I am not referring to any of them.

Comment: @Aakash : anyway, you should have `<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />` in your `<http>` bloc.